# Why am i receiving this error- json.decode.JSONDecodeError:expecting value: line 1 clumn 1 (char 0)?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to append all the data for each result in the loop into one json file.

Here is my code:

```
for obj in all_psts: # There About 245 objs
    for i in range(1, 500):
        s = requests.Session()
        s.proxies = <my_proxy>
        resp = s.get("https://api/ur/{0}/recipients?page={1}".format(obj, i),
                     headers=header, verify=False).json()
        if resp: # If the page is not empty
            a = []
            a.extend(a)
            with open(pst_rec_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
                json.dump(a, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=1, sort_keys=False, default=str)
        elif not resp: #if there is no data, stop the statement and run the next obj
            print('should stop and go to next obj')
            continue
```

However I keep receiving this error message:

```
 raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any ideas or suggestions as to why I keep receiving this error?

Comment: The website returned `None`. Hence it throws that error

Comment: how do u bypass that tho and continue

Comment: so when it reaches the website of none, ignore error and move to next object

Comment: Use `try/except`